# How to ignore any empty values in a perl grep?

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

I am using the following to count the number of occurrences of a pattern in a file:

```
my @lines = grep /$text/, <$fp>;
print ($#lines + 1);
```

But sometimes it prints one more than the actual value. I checked and it is because the last element of `@lines` is null, and that is also counted.

How can the last element of the grep result be empty sometimes? Also, how can this issue be resolved?

Comment: why are you adding 1 to `$#lines`?

Comment: Without knowing what the pattern is we don't have much of a chance understanding why it's matching on a "empty" line.  However, do keep in mind that lines terminate with \n, which counts as something to match against.  And in fact some patterns can match against nothing at all.

Comment: @sergio, because `$#lines` gives the index of last element of the array (which is length - 1 as it starts from 0)

Comment: @Lazer: `print scalar @lines;` to print how many lines are in the array `@lines`. `$#lines` is the top index, which is not synonymous with number of elements.

Comment: For anyone to be able to answer this question, you need to specify what `$text` is. Else it's like asking: "There's something wrong with my car! What is it?"

Comment: An edit flip-flop later, I feel I need to ask:  What exactly does "is null" mean in the question?

Answer (score 6):

It really depends a lot on your pattern, but one thing you could do is join a couple of matches, the first one disqualifying any line that contains only space (or nothing).  This example will reject any line that is either empty, newline only, or any amount of whitespace only.

```
my @lines = grep { not /^\s*$/ and /$test/ } <$fp>;
```

Keep in mind that if the contents of $test happen to include regexp special metacharacters they either need to be intended for their metacharacter purposes, or sterilized with `quotemeta()`.

My theories are that you might have a line terminated in \n which is somehow matching your $text regexp, or your $text regexp contains metacharacters in it that are affecting the match without you being aware.  Either way, the snippet I provided will at least force rejection of "blank lines", where blank could mean completely empty (unlikely), newline terminated but otherwise empty (probable), or whitespace containing (possible) lines that appear blank when printed.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression that matches the empty string will match `undef`.  Perl will warn about doing so, but casts `undef` to `''` before trying to match against it, at which point `grep` will quite happily promote the `undef` to its results.  If you don't want to pick up the empty string (or anything that will be matched as though it were the empty string), you need to rewrite your regular expression to not match it.

Comment: but a list-context `<>` shouldn't ever return undef.

Comment: That's a good point.  Which means I screwed up in a couple of ways.  I wish Lazer would come back and explain what 'null' means.

Comment: I suspect he doesn't actually know what his variable contains, which is why my answer was to inspect it :)

Answer (score 2):

To accurately see what is in lines, do:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper \@lines;
```

Comment: There's an old module that never really gets old.  For debugging and generally wrapping ones head around datastructures, Data::Dumper is a first line tool.  Just a few days ago its ability to bring visibility to whitespace saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since no more information about the contents of `$text` (the regex) is forthcoming, I guess I'll toss out some general information.

Consider the following example:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (' ', 1, 2, 'a', '');
print Dumper [ grep /\s*/, @array ];
```

We get:

```
$VAR1 = [
          ' ',
          1,
          2,
          'a',
          ''
        ];
```

All the values match. Why? Because they also match the empty string. To get what we want, we need `\s` or `\s+`. (There will be no practical difference between the two)

You may have such a problem.