# Filtering empty strings in array from split in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, split

I was originally puzzled by this: I was just working on a character splitting function in Perl, when I noticed this:

```
  DB<56> map(print("-", $_, "\n"), split( //, "test")  );
-t
-e
-s
-t

  DB<57> map(print("-", $_, "\n"), split( /./, "test")  );

  DB<58> map(print("-", $_, "\n"), split( /(.)/, "test")  );
-
-t
-
-e
-
-s
-
-t
```

I already knew that [if the empty regex // is used, the string is split into individual characters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html); but I wasn't clear on where did those empty strings in the `/(.)/` regex come from - but just a few sentences later, the page states "*If the regex has groupings, then the list produced contains the matched substrings from the groupings as well ... Since the first character of $x matched the regex, split prepended an empty initial element to the list.*" So, it's expected behavior. (althgouh, I'm still not clear why ungrouped dot `/./` doesn't do anything )

But, I was also working in Python, and encountered a similar problem (empty strings in result of split) - and there I found a `filter(None, list)` function, which in this invocation, simply removes empty strings from a list. What is used to achieve the same in Perl?

Comment: You'll see a better picture if you pass `-1` for `split`'s third arg.

Comment: Using `map` as a foreach loop is frowned upon. Aside from the small inefficiencies, it promises one thing to the reader but does another. (`print "-$_\n" for split ...;`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument of [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) defines what separates the terms of the list you are parsing. In your last two snippets, you tell `split` that any character is a valid separator, so `split` returns what's between the characters of the input: Five empty strings.

```
>perl -E"say qq{<$_>} for split /./, 'test', -1;"
<>
<>
<>
<>
<>
```

(Trailing empty strings are filtered out by default.)

The solution is not to start filtering out the very thing you asked `split` to produce. Either fix your separator

```
my @chars = split /(?<=.)|(?=.)/s;
my @chars = split //;
```

or use a better tool

```
my @chars = /(.)/s;
my @chars = unpack '(a)*', $_;
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @ikegami - and sorry for the late accept; however, if in principle (with a different regex) I get an array with empty strings which I'd like to filter, now would I do that (like Python's `filter(None, list)`)? I've heard `@arr = grep { defined } @arr;` should work, but I just tried it, and it still leaves empty strings...

Comment: Ah, found it via [How to ignore any empty values in a perl grep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631043/how-to-ignore-any-empty-values-in-a-perl-grep/6631252#6631252): it should be `@arr = grep { not /^\s*$/ } @arr;` - that filters out empty strings. Cheers!

Comment: `grep { !length } @arr`